# React-Redux - No reducer provided for key "coins"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Not sure why I'm getting the following errors.

I'm just setting up my store, actions and reducers, I haven't called dispatch on anything yet.

#### Expected

App runs fine, Redux state is not updated

#### Results

[image]

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducer from './reducer'

import App from './App'
import css from './coinhover.scss'

const element = document.getElementById('coinhover');

const store = createStore(reducer, compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <App />
    </Provider>, element);
```

src/reducer/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { coins } from './coins'

export default combineReducers({
    coins
});
```

src/reducer/actions/coins.js

```
import * as api from '../../services/api'
import { storage, addToPortfolio } from '../../services/coinFactory'

export const ADD_COIN = 'ADD_COIN'

export function getCoin(coin) {
    return dispatch => {
        api.getCoin(coin)
            .then((res_coin)  => addToPortfolio(res_coin))
            .then((portfolio) => dispatch(updatePortfolio(portfolio)));
    }
}

export function updatePortfolio(portfolio) {
    return {
        type: ADD_COIN,
        portfolio
    }
}
```

finally src/reducer/coins/index.js

```
import { ADD_COIN } from './actions'

const initialState = [];

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_COIN:
            return action.portfolio;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Your issue lies with how you're importing your `coins` reducer:

```
import { coins } from './coins'
```

The latter tries to obtain a named export returned from the file in ./coins.

You are not using any named exports only `export default`, therefore you just need to import the file as follows:

```
import coins from './coins';
```

Using the latter will result with the fact that `coins` will then contain the value of `export default`; which will be the coins reducer.

Answer (score 42):

Even when all your imports are correctly imported, this can still happen for one other reason. Circular Dependency!

In my case, this happeded because of a circular dependency in a file. I had two circular dependecy in the project that I created accedentally. Example: `rootReducer.ts -> authSlice.ts -> rootReducer.ts`.

These dependencies are often not as easy to debug. I used [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dpdm) package to check for circular dependencies. Once the circular dependency was removed, all was well.

Comment: This saved me. Note you can use it without adding to your project via `npx dpdm ./src/index.tsx`

Answer (score 10):

Ah just found it, I was importing my coins reducer incorrectly...

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import coins from './coins' // because I have coins/index.js

export default combineReducers({
    coins
});
```

instead of

```
import { coins } from './coins'
```

Comment: Your correction is correct but your reasoning is incorrect. Please see my answer. The cause of your issue was due to the fact that you were not using a named export of `coins`

Comment: If someone is still confused just remove {} from coins on import statement

Answer (score 5):

This was my fix:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { coins } from './coins'

export default combineReducers({
    coinsState: coins || (() => null) // By adding this I resolved it.
});
```

Comment: This won't actually fix the problem and will just mask the real error. See the answers above for likely real resolutions

Answer (score 1):

If nothing worked for you this might be a circular dependency. I had a project like that requiring store state in the slice. Instead of using the store there was a thunk available that can provide you with the state without importing the store itself. If you have this edge case you can get state from thunk.

```
thunkAPI.getState()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not adding a default property to my reducers. When I added it, it worked.
here is my code;

```
const counterReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
      case 'INCREMENT':
        return state + 1;
      case 'DECREMENT':
          return state - 1;
      default:
        return state;    
    }
  }
  
export default counterReducer;
```

and combinde file;

```
import   counter   from './counter';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    counter: counter,
   
});

export default allReducers;
```

Answer (score 0):

*i cannot get* **products**
there is my code on *Admin.js*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfo3j.png)

```
const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.array)
console.log(products);
```

and when i run it i got a error ***Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'array')***

and there is my *store.js* code :

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import productSlice from "./reducers/productSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        products: productSlice
    }
})
```

there is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);
```

there is my productSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const productSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'products',
    initialState: { array: [] },
    reducers: {
        setProductArr: (state, action) => {
            state.array = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const { setProductArr } = productSlice.actions

export default productSlice.reducers
```

*sorry this is my first time asking to stackoverflow*

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34301469)