# React Native: console.error: "No reducer provide for key "auth""

Tags: react-native, redux, reducers

I am working on a React Native application and I am getting the following error in my simulator:

> console.error: "No reducer provide for key "auth""

It is unclear to me as to why I am getting this error. Here I am saying:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    email: state.auth.email
  };
};
```

give me the email that is coming from `state.auth.email`, and it is specifically `auth` because that is the value I assigned my reducer to in my `combineReducer` call in my `index.js` file:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { AuthReducer } from './AuthReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer
});
```

My reducer is what is actually producing this email property at the end here: `email: state.auth.email`.

So, I don't know why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem already has a solution on SO:
[React-Redux - No reducer provided for key "coins"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791528/react-redux-no-reducer-provided-for-key-coins)

Your issue lies with how you are importing your `AuthReducer` reducer:
`import { AuthReducer } from './AuthReducer';`
Similar to your case, you are not using any named exports, but instead `export default`, therefore you only need to import the `AuthReducer` like so:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer
});
```

Comment: sorry, I did not see that post in my search. thank you.